# jquery fancybox input focus

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-selectors, fancybox

I am using cakephp 1.3 and fancybox..I have managed to put a form in fancybox.Now i want to focus cursor into the one of the input field. I am pretty tired of trying many thing.My code given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
//document.getElementById('frmname.answer').focus(); 
jQuery("a#answer").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'    :  600, 
        'speedOut'   :  200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'href'  : this.href,
});

}); /* */
</script>
```

I tried following things

```
'onComplete' : function() {
               $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#answer').focus();
            },
```

and

```
$('#answer').focus();
```

in my script.But no good result>can any one point out the wrong i am doing with my code.Thanks in advance.

My fancybox content is like this:

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='reply'>

        <h1>Reply For <?php echo $offer['OfferBoard']['headline'] ?></h1>


        <ul class="nrml_list" > 

                <?php echo $this->Form->create('OfferAnswer',array('id'=>'frm','name'=>'frmname'), array('action' => 'reply/'.$offer['OfferBoard']['id'],'inputDefaults'=> array('label'=>false))); ?>


                <li> 
                    <div class='ulabel' style="float:right;" >Reply Text</div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="left"><?php echo $form->textarea('answer',array('class'=>'tarea1','label'=>FALSE,'id'=>'answer')); ?></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>  
                </li>

                <li> 
                    <div class='ulabel' ></div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="left"><?php 
                                $attributes=array('type'=>'checkbox','div'=>false,'value' => '1','hiddenField' => false,'label'=>FALSE);
                                echo $this->Form->input('copy_to',$attributes)." Send Copy ";  
                        ?></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>  
                </li>



        </ul>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end('Reply'); ?>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
//without quotes in onComplete, this worked for me
onComplete: function() {
   $('#answer').focus();
},
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanx brother...i am bad at scripts

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake with the selector ID.  I was using the same ID from both the link which I used to popup `fancybox` and for the selector field, i.e. `answer`.
I renamed form field id to `ans`...and its working fine. And thanks @Sudhir,
correct code given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
//document.frm.elements['data[OfferAnswer][answer]'].focus(); 
jQuery("a#answer").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'    :  600, 
        'speedOut'   :  200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'href'  : this.href,
        onComplete : function() {
                    $('#ans').focus();
                        },
});

}); /* */
</script>
```

The new form element is:

```
<?php echo $form->textarea('answer',array('class'=>'tarea1','label'=>FALSE,'id'=>'ans')); ?>
```